# Запуск части кода *.bat файла в определенный день недели

Tags: cmd, bat

Необходимо чтобы Батник запускал части кода в заданные дни недели.
Что то типа:

понедельник

```
F:\OpenServer\modules\database\MySQL-5.7\bin\mysqldump diplome --user=root > backup1.sql
```

вторник

```
F:\OpenServer\modules\database\MySQL-5.7\bin\mysqldump diplome --user=root > backup2.sql
```

среда

```
F:\OpenServer\modules\database\MySQL-5.7\bin\mysqldump diplome --user=root > backup3.sql
```

...

Воскресение

```
F:\OpenServer\modules\database\MySQL-5.7\bin\mysqldump diplome --user=root > backup7.sql
```

И чтобы когда есть уже файлы с таким названием, новые заменяли их.

Comment: А если планировщиком 7 разных батников запускать?

Comment: Для показанных кодов разумнее 7 заданий, но один батник. Просто запускаемый в разных заданиях с разными параметрами.

Answer (score 1):

Следующий *комментированный* `.bat` скрипт может помочь

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,*" %%G in ('
          wmic path win32_localtime get dayofweek^, year  ^| findstr "2"
          ') do (

    rem совместный код для все дни
    echo backup%%G.sql
    set "_dayofweek=%%G"

    rem код для каждого конкретного дня надо (лучше всего) сделать в подпрограмме
    call :day%%G
)
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:day1
  echo %_dayofweek% Mon
goto :eof

:day2
  echo %_dayofweek% Tue
goto :eof

:day3
  echo %_dayofweek% Wen
goto :eof

:day4
  echo %_dayofweek% Thu
goto :eof

:day5
  echo %_dayofweek% Fri
goto :eof

:day6
  echo %_dayofweek% Sat
goto :eof

:day0
  echo %_dayofweek% Sun
goto :eof
```

**Результат**:

```
==> D:\bat\SU_ru\634597.bat
backup5.sql
5 Fri

==>
```

Comment: а где метка :eof ? скрипт не выполняется, вылет по ошибке

Comment: @Konstantin https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html *Метка `EOF` - это особый случай - используя `GOTO :EOF` всегда будет передавать выполнение в конце текущего пакетного файла или конца текущей подпрограммы.
Это может быть написано как `Goto:EOF` или `GOTO :EOF`. Пространство является необязательным.*

Answer (score 0):

Можно  использовать `wmic path win32_localtime get dayofweek`, это возвращает номер дня недели, а затем в цикле просто перебирать значения и запускать что надо.